# Risks of directly getting DirectByteBuffer address in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a JNI library which accepts a DirectByteBuffer and operates over it.

To get the buffer address, I was using:

```cpp
(unsigned char *) env->GetDirectBufferAddress(input)
```

That was good, but after profiling it I noticed that a long time was spent in `jni_IsInstanceOf`:

[image: profiler].

I then replaced it with direct access to `Buffer.address`

```cpp
java_nio_Buffer = env->FindClass("java/nio/Buffer");
java_nio_Buffer_address = env->GetFieldID(java_nio_Buffer, "address", "J");
(...)
(unsigned char *) env->GetLongField(input, java_nio_Buffer_address)
```

That caused a *huge* speedup in that code.

Are there any major risks in getting a DirectByteBuffer address that way, given I know my object will always be a DirectByteBuffer?

Comment: If your memory management model allows it, you could keep a list of `(jobject, void *)` pairs as a cache and use `env->IsSameObject()` as a lookup function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 9+ apparently makes access to the `address` field illegal via reflection.

Google posted an issue with protobuf:  [**JDK 9 warning: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil to field java.nio.Buffer.address #3781**](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3781).

Note the posted error message:

> ```
> WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
> WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
>     (file:/Users/mmueller/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/b32aba0cbe737a4ca953f71688725972e3ee927c/protobuf-java-3.4.0.jar)
>     to field java.nio.Buffer.address
> WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil
> WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
> WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
> ```

Given the `All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release` warning, it appears you risk future versions of Java potentially preventing access to the field, even via JNI.

It may also be possible, depending on how you use the field's value, that the address of the underlying buffer could change out from under you.

And finally, you're dependent on the internal implementation of the class.  Should that change, your code will be broken.

You'll have to weigh those risks against the benefits you get from accessing the field directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm aware of those points, except "that the address of the underlying buffer could change out from under you". Is that true for DirectByteBuffers? I know that managed `byte[]` can be moved by the GC, and that's why I have to use `env->GetByteArrayElements()` and `env->ReleaseByteArrayElements()`, but I was assuming that wasn't the case for DirectByteBuffers.

Comment: @JuanLopes I don't *think* the buffer can move out from under you with a DirectByteBuffer, but AFAIK there's no actual guarantees that it won't if you don't use the public methods or the JVM's JNI API to access the buffer's address.